# Showing spinner and loading activity with Angular and ngRx

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I am developing a Angular app using ngRx and trying to exercise its best practices. But I came to place where I couldn't find how to proceed correctly, and that's dealing with async ops when they are happening, and providing proper **feedback to the user**!

It is very nice to offer feedback from the user and also prevent him from hitting a send button twice, but, again, I am not clear how to to that in a good manner using Angular and ngrx. Back in AngularJs, I used AngularUiBlock, which can intercept ALL http requests and show block-ui div (which prevents the buttons to be clicked) and also a nice **spinner**, but I did not found such a solution for ng2. Should I use a global action for loading and a global effect for showing this elements? Should every component have to implement this logic?

Comment: Why don't you show the code you have attempted?

Comment: I use ng-busy in my apps for this purpose https://github.com/devyumao/angular2-busy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way is to track server interactions within your model state:

```
export interface ItemState {
  entities: { [id: number]: Item };
  loaded: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
}

export const initialState: ItemState = {
  entities: {},
  loaded: false,
  loading: false
};
```

Then your reducers should edit them properly when updating the app state depending on the dispatched action. Maybe like this:

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, action: fromItems.ItemsAction): ItemState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case fromItems.CREATE_ITEM:
    case fromItems.LOAD_ITEMS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    }

    case fromItems.CREATE_ITEM_SUCCESS:
    case fromItems.LOAD_ITEMS_SUCCESS: {
      const items = action.payload;
      const entities = ...
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        loaded: true,
        entities
      };
    }

    case fromItems.CREATE_ITEM_FAIL:
    case fromItems.LOAD_ITEMS_FAIL: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        loaded: false
      };
    }
    ...
```

You can also see a similar example here in [the official ngrx demo app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/95dd2dc2c870477572784044b0be46a2876ef43b/example-app/app/books/reducers/collection.ts). You also need to create selectors for them as it is done [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/95dd2dc2c870477572784044b0be46a2876ef43b/example-app/app/books/reducers/index.ts#L130-L137) so they could be observed by your components.

**The main idea is the following:**

1. Your component dispatch an action `GET_ITEMS` *(as example)*
2. Your reducers will set the `state.loading` to `true`
3. a side effect listening to the `GET_ITEMS` action will fire a **http** call to backend server. Then depending on the received response the same side effect will dispatch either a `GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS` or `GET_ITEMS_FAIL` action.
4. your reducer should re-create a new state with updated `loaded` and `loading` values. By the meanwhile your component is observing them and updating your DOM by showing or hiding/disabling data accordingly.

Comment: Using httpClietn interceptor https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events you can see the progress. If you use a service to save the percent with a observable Subject and you subscribe the changes in your component

Comment: The problem with all the examples on the interweb is that they all require state objects for loading in each feature state. Its just a lot of repetition. We want one spinner to be activated on a project level not individual spinners in each feature branch. Me thinks BehaviourSubject is a better fit for this non data store action.

Comment: @DarrenStreet The reason you need to have loading state for each state slice (or even for each entity in the store) is that you need to individually track which loading action has finished, since the loading API calls can happen in parallel and complete in any order.


If you want to reduce boilerplate, take a look at this lib: https://github.com/amzhang/ngrx-loading-state


There is a global reducer functionality in there to handle showing snackbar messages on any API error. You can adapt that to show a global loading spinner.